# How to reference constants from multiple files without a 'uses' b?

Tags: delphi

I have a some constants defined in unit uMainWindow for broadcast messaging, for example:

```
const 
  UM_QUIT = WM_USER + 12;
  UM_PROCESS_MESSAGES = WM_USER + 13;
```

Now I need a couple more broadcast messages, but they're going to be used on a different form (lets call it uOtherWindow), not uMainWindow. I'd like to keep all the broadcast messages together so I don't accidentally reuse a message number. I'd prefer not to force uOtherWindow and uMainWindow to be dependent on each other, so simply adding `uMainWindow` to the uses list for `uOtherWindow` is out.

How should I include this set of constants to both classes?

Here are the (may or may not be feasible) ideas I've had so far:

- a new unit `uConstants.pas` and put that in the uses statement for both classes.
- put them in an include file like `broadcastconstants.inc` and then have each class include that file with a compiler directive `{$Include broadcastconstants.inc}`

Comment: Go for uConstants.pas!

Comment: I agree with Uwe.  Create a new unit, you can name it uConstants.pas, and put all the constants there.  Then put uConstants in the uses clause of both units.

Comment: Please don't broadcast those messages. Broadcasting sends messages to *all* top-level windows in the system, including windows from other programs. You have no idea how those other program will react to those messages. When broadcasting, you should only use messages IDs reserved by `RegisterWindowMessage` at run time. See documentation at `SendMessage` for details.

Comment: If, instead of broadcasting, you just mean you're *sending* messages to windows in your program, you still don't really need to worry about ID overlap. Each form in your program represents a different class, and each class of window gets its own set of window messages, starting at `wm_User`. You should never send a `MainWindow` message to an `OtherWindow` or vice versa, so it doesn't matter whether they interpret a given message ID differently. If you're really sending the same messages to two different window classes, then you should base them on `wm_App` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put the constants in an include file then you will end up with multiple definitions of the constants, one for each `$INCLUDE` directive. If you put the constants in a dedicated unit then there will be a single declaration. For constants this is not so important but for types this would be a critical issue.

As well as that issue, units are easier to work with in the IDE than include files.

So, all in all, I would advise you to use a dedicated unit.